# Hazel-cast Cache Key-Values availability on all nodes/Member

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I am using hazelCast to cache the data getting fetched from API.
Structure of the API is something like this

```
Controller->Service->DAOLayer->DB
```

I am keeping @Cacheable at service layer where getData(int elementID) method is present.

In my architecture there are two PaaS nodes (np3a, np4a). API will be deployed on both of them and users will be accessing them via loadBalancer IP, which will redirect them to either of the nodes.

So It might be possible that for one hit from User X request goes to np3a and for another hit from same user request goes to np4a.

I want that in the very first hit when I would be caching the response on np3a, the same cached response is also available for next hit to np4a.

I have read about

1. **ReplicatedMaps** : Memory inefficient
2. **NearCache** : when read>write

I am not sure which one approach to take or if you suggest something entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 nodes, Hazelcast will partition data so that half of it will be on node 1, and the other half on node 2. It means there's a 50% chance a user will ask the node containing the data.

If you want to avoid in all cases an additional network request to fetch data that is not present on a node, the only way is to copy data each time to every node. That's the goal of `ReplicatedMap`. That's the trade-off: performance vs. memory consumption.

`NearCache` adds an additional cache on the "client-side", if you're using client-server architecture (as opposed to embedded).

Comment: thanks @Nicolas; Can you please suggest a good reference page for ReplicatedMap implementation.

Comment: and I think we can not user replicated map with @cacheable?

Comment: and what is IMap?

Comment: I think the official documentation is quite exhaustive on `ReplicatedMap` https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#replicated-map

I'm not sure about `@Cacheable` being able to use another mechanism

`IMap` is the standard distributed data structure. It allows you to partition your data, so that you don't use too much memory, at the cost of a possible extra network request if the desired key/value is not stored on the node.

Comment: exhaustive but truly confusing for a newbie

Comment: Hazelcast offers a Gitter channel https://gitter.im/hazelcast/hazelcast If you have specific questions, I'd suggest you write them here. Any feedback appreciated